# how to select most recent date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

**EDIT VERSION**

**EMPLOYEE TABLE**

```
|ID | employee_id |   Name             |   
| 1 | 123         | John Richard       | 
| 2 | 554         | Daniel Domingo     |
```

**educational background**

```
|ID | employee_id | School/institute   | date graduated |
| 1 | 123         | highschool         | 2007           |
| 2 | 123         | college            | 2011           |
| 3 | 554         | college            | 2010           |
| 4 | 554         | masteral           | 2013           |
```

**job title**

```
|ID | employee_id | Job description    |
| 1 | 123         | Free lancer        |
| 2 | 554         | admin assistant    |
```

i need to select the latest date info of the employee's educational background

the result would be

**result query**

```
|ID | employee_id | Name               | Job title       | year_graduated | school_institute |
| 1 | 123         | John Richard       | Free Lancer     |    2011        | college          |
| 2 | 554         | Daniel Domingo     | Admin Assistant |    2013        | masteral         |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM tableA ORDER BY employee_id, date_graduated DESC) A 
GROUP BY employee_id
```

**OR**

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tableA a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT employee_id, MAX(date_graduated) maxDate 
            FROM tableA GROUP BY employee_id
          ) b ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id AND a.date_graduated = b.maxDate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT employee_id ,MAX([date graduated]) FROM Table GROUP BY [employee_id]
```

The result is

```
employee_id | date graduated
----------------------------
        123 | 2011 
        554 | 2013
```

Comment: i tried your query and it produces that employee 123 and highschool level.

Answer (score 1):

Subquery will return the maximum date for every employee, you should then join this subquery with your table to return the full row:

```
SELECT yourtable.*
FROM
  yourtable INNER JOIN (SELECT employee_id, MAX(`date graduated`) max_date
                        FROM yourtable
                        GROUP BY employee_id) m
  ON yourtable.employee_id = m.employee_id
     AND yourtable.`date graduated` = m.max_date
```

Answer (score 1):

for employee 123

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` 
WHERE employee_id=123 
ORDER BY date_graduated DESC LIMIT 1
```

for employee 554

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` 
WHERE employee_id=554
ORDER BY date_graduated DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM t
GROUP BY employee_id
HAVING date_graduated=max(date graduated)
```

and you'll get the desired result

Comment: some of the date is not selected, and the first input in the database is selected and group by

Comment: @Vincent I've tested my query and the result of it is the following as you needed

Comment: @Vincent Do you have the result with 1 and 3 IDs?